# Authenticate Calls made to Salesforce webservice

Tags: json, webservices, rest, authentication

I am using this exact example from trailhead
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Cases/*')
    global with sharing class CaseManager {
     @HttpGet
       global static Case getCaseById() {
       RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
       // grab the caseId from the end of the URL
       String caseId = request.requestURI.substring(
       request.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
       Case result =  [SELECT CaseNumber,Subject,Status,Origin,Priority
                    FROM Case
                    WHERE Id = :caseId];
       return result;
      }
  }
```

I used Workbench to invoke the GET HTTP method by following these exact steps

1. In Workbench, select GET.
2. Enter the URI /services/apexrest/Cases/, replacing  with the ID of the record you created in the previous step.
3. Click Execute.

   This invocation calls the method associated with the GET HTTP method, 
   namely the getCaseById method.
4. To view the response returned, click Show Raw Response.

So far so good, I see the raw JSON response as expected.

Now i want to give this endpoint to a third party, so that they can invoke this webservice from an external app, and get the response exactly as i got when executed from workbench.

**My question is -**

How do I authhenticate the call made by third party app?

Would the third party use the entire URI like   https://myOrgInstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/ 
insead of just /services/apexrest/Cases/

Comment: thanks! I will look into the post.

Comment: Also have a look at [Integration Patterns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_intro_overview.htm) for a higher-level architectural overview

Comment: I was able to call the REST API endpoint from Postman, and get the response from Salesforce as desired. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the third-party would use `https://domain.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Cases/`. To authenticate, they would use OAuth or the SOAP login() command, and set the Authorization header to `Authorization: Bearer <session-id-or-access-token>`. See the [Web Server OAuth Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_web_server_oauth_flow.htm), the [User-Agent Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_user_agent_oauth_flow.htm), and SOAP [login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm). You can also use the [Canvas API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_connect.meta/platform_connect/canvas_framework_intro.htm) to log in "Facebook-style" to the third-party app.

Comment: Thank you. I will read the documentation provided in the links

Comment: @user4947 No problem! There's several different options available, so they can choose whichever method is easiest for them. Also see my edit in case you missed it about the Canvas API, too.

Comment: Thank you. Salesforce will not be logging in to the third party app. The third party app will call salesforce to get the newly created records in salesforce, and then the third party will post updates to these records to salesforce. Do you think Canvas API is relevant to my UseCase?

Comment: I have a question about what you mentioned in your response 'To authenticate, they would use OAuth or the SOAP login() command, and set the Authorization header to Authorization: Bearer <session-id-or-access-token>'. Does this mean I will have to create a user in salesforce for the third party app? If not, how would this app generate the Access Token with just a consumer key and consumer secret?

Comment: @user4947 (a) Yes, the Canvas API could be a valid use case in that scenario. It's not just about logging in to the third-party app (though that may be part of the process), it's to provide some access to Salesforce as well. You should at least read about it and see if it makes sense for you. (b) Aside from very limited "public Site" functionality, almost all functions require a valid user account. This may be a dedicated Integration User, or the login of a System Administrator. OAuth is preferred, as password-based authentication will fail when the user changes their password.

Comment: Thank You !! I will read about Canvas API. Thank you for explaining point (b). Much appreciated